# Retrieve all "li" without hardcoding it

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Goal :
Retrieve the data of the `<li>` without **hardcoding** each specific `li`

Problem :
I have the code but it **doesn't work**. What am I missing?

```
IList<IWebElement> ddffd = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("[@class='test']/li"));
```

Info :
**The quantity of `li` is changing iterative**.

Html :

```
<ul class="test">
   <li>a</li>
   <li>b</li>
   <li>d</li>   
   <li>a</li>
   <li>b</li>
   <li>d</li>   
</ul>
```

Comment: Your xPath is wrong -> "//ul[@class='test']/li"

Comment: How should I write it?

Comment: the best way is :  IList<IWebElement> liList = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='test']")).FindElements(By.TagName("li"));

Comment: @LeonBarkan I think the best way is using a single `xpath` and not using `find` twice. `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='test']/li"))`

Comment: use this as cssSelector:  ul.test>li   ... this will return all li

Comment: the best case is not using xpath at all it's much slower that find the elements by (id/name...) but when must to use the xpath i didn't think you will feel the difference between the two, but in the button line in your case is that you must to start the xpath with "//ul..." or "//* ..."

Comment: @HelloWorld if the cssSelector works, i will convert this to answer

Comment: The answer is cssSelector

Comment: @HelloWorld convert this to answer ... and glad to know that this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get it by using a cssSelector like below:

```
IList<IWebElement> ddffd = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("ul.test>li"));
foreach (IWebElement e in ddffd)
{
    // do something with e
}
```